# Javascript for loop to filter conversion

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have following script which filter the data using for loop as shown

```
let i;
const filteredFriends = [];

for (i = 0; i < users.length; i += 1) {
  if (this.isUserExist(users[i]) {
    filteredFriends.push(users[i]);
  }
}
```

How can i covert it into filter

any idea please

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: @Nicolas i tried using filter but nothing works for me

Comment: @MunishKapoor So you *did* try something, but it didn't work. We'd appreciate if you posted your failed attempts so we can help you understand what you did wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the `if` condition in the callback function of `filter()`. Replace `user[i]` with the callback function parameter.

```
const filteredFriends = users.filter(u => this.isUserExist(u))
```

Make sure you use an arrow function so that `this` will be inherited in the callback function. If you need compatibility with older implementations that don't have arrow functions, see [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

```
let filteredFriends = users.filter(user => {
    return this.isUserExist(user);
});
```

Comment: Please don't post code without a textual explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
const users = ['spray', 'limit', 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];
let filteredFriends = users.filter(user => this.isUserExist(user));
console.log(filteredFriends);
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` method need to return boolean value. your function `this.isUserExist` seems doing that as you have used in if condition.

Use it like.

```
const filteredFriends = users.filter(this.isUserExist);
```